# Where are my Like Clockwork and Too Cool hats?

Tags: support, android-app, winter-bash, consecutive-days, winter-bash-2017

I've visited 94 days consecutively but haven't got my Like Clockwork hat, or any other, as I've up voted more than 7 times from my Android app so I'm eligible for another hat but haven't got any.

Comment: You have to do all the activity during the event, before the event activity will not be consider.

Answer (score 13):

The Like Clockwork app is for visiting the site for 10 consecutive days **during Winter Bash 2017**. For the 'Too Cool' app, you need to be using the **official** Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange app (and the votes need to be during Winter Bash 2017 as well).